# Google Storage JSON API missing folders item

Tags: json, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

i'm using Google Storage JSON API to get a json with all items inside my bucket to create a treelist inside my application.
My problem is that some folders items are missing inside this JSON. 
This is the output of a folder item:

```
{
        "kind": "storage#object",
        "id": "id",
        "selfLink": "selfLink",
        "name": "pdf/",
        "bucket": "bucket-name",
        "generation": "1461762807657000",
        "metageneration": "1",
        "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        "timeCreated": "2016-04-27T13:13:27.626Z",
        "updated": "2016-04-27T13:13:27.626Z",
        "storageClass": "STANDARD",
        "timeStorageClassUpdated": "2016-04-27T13:13:27.626Z",
        "size": "0",
        "md5Hash": "",
        "mediaLink": "link",
        "crc32c": "",
        "etag": ""
    }
```

This is PDF folder, but for example Video folder missing despite items inside this folder are available in the JSON.
I obtain the same result trying API in this page [Google Storage Object List](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list)

Comment: Is there a `pageToken` returned from your listing call?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage has a flat namespace, so "Folders" don't actually exist.  Instead we have a ListObject API with 'prefix' and 'delimiter' options, which allow for a very inefficient simulation of a hierarchy by setting 'prefix' to the "folder" you want to list, and setting the delimiter to '/'.  This results in all of the objects in that folder being returned in the list call, and any "folders" being returned as common_prefixes.

Unfortunately what this means is that you can't actually 'create' a folder in google cloud storage.  Folders only exist if there are objects in them, so when someone creates a "folder" in the UI, the UI creates a zero byte placeholder object in the folder with the name "", in order to make the "folder" exist.

If someone uploads a file with a name that places it into a folder without creating that folder via the UI first then this placeholder object will never be created.